# ASP.Net: Keepalive code execution

Tags: asp.net

I have a windows service that is calling a page on our website for two reasons: 1) to keep the site alive, and 2) to execute a web service method which also lives on this website.

On page_Load, the web service instance (SvcTaskRun) is coded to execute the RunTasks() method, which I currently have set to send an email each time it gets called, but will later execute a series of automated tasks.

```
Sub page_load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim SvcTaskRun As New MyTaskRunSvc.TaskRunSvc

    Dim TaskListComplete As String = SvcTaskRun.RunTasks

End Sub
```

Right now, I'm just trying to get it to run (send the email) each time my keepalive page loads.

So my IIS log tells me that the windows service is getting a ststus code of 200 each time it performs a GET on keepalive.aspx.

But, the page load code apparently doesn't execute.

Question: Any idea why this isn't working?
Question: How can I instantiate debugging while I wait for the execution of Page_Load? Never used Attach to process or anything before, only debugged using F5/F11.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes here looking for an answer, here's what I did to fix this issue.

Apparently the website didn't want to call its own web method from its own web service. I imagine something may have been wrong with ASPNET permissions, but since the RunTasks method no longer needed to be called from outside the website due to architecture changes, I simply moved the RunTasks methods to a class as part of the web application and called it internally and voila, it works.

Comment: Nice to you updated your own question with the answer, could you also accept the answer then? :)